# Is there a difference between the two?

Tags: java

```
1.  Student student;

2.  Student student = new Student();
```

just confused between those. :D

I tried them both but still don't know the difference.

Comment: Yes there is. Read a basic tutorial.

Comment: Try to access an attribute and you will see the difference...

Comment: @vbail That's the bullet point. Good.

Comment: No need for the downvotes. As a beginner you may be dazzled by the slightest thing.

Comment: @AliAlamiri As a beginner he should read the basics before posting such a question that shows **no efforts** and **minimal research**.

Comment: Agreed, it's a legitimate question. Needs a better title though.

Comment: @MarounMaroun He may have read something and not understood it, it happens. Also I think one of SO purposes is to help with these kind of things.

Comment: @AliAlamiri Then he should elaborate, what exactly he didn't understand. At least to show us that he did a minimal research.

Comment: I agree with @MarounMaroun

Comment: Downvotes uncalled for, but then its a case of SO being highly under-utilized.

Comment: @MarounMaroun He did say he's confused between the two. Isn't that enough to tell what the OP problem is? If he's confused about something, we can simply clear it up for him. Asking a question is considered minimal research.

Comment: @AliAlamiri After you look at the docs, you'll see that the answer relies there, this is even more minimal.

Comment: Thanks sir AliAlamiri and MarounMaroun. ;)

Comment: THis is what I've Tried. Now I know the difference of the two. ;) sir Stathis Andronikos (commented below) answered.hehe! It's just that, why the 'Student student' returns Null exception when setting/getting the value. Now I know. hehe! Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Student student;
```

Just declares reference variable `student` of type `Student`. At this point `student` is `null`

```
Student student = new Student();
```

will create new object of `Student` class and assign reference to `student`.

> The new operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new object and returning a reference to that memory. The new operator also invokes the object constructor.
>   The phrase "instantiating a class" means the same thing as "creating an object."

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the effort and clear explanation sir. :)

Comment: @Clem: Refer [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) for more. I hope you will even get clear about object. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks sir ;) I'm starting to love Java. HAHA! :D

Answer (score 1):

`Student student;` declares a variable named `student` is that is of type `Student`. It will have the default value of `null`.

`Student student = new Student();` declares a variable named `student` of type `Student`, but it also assign a newly constructed Student object to it.

It's similar to the difference between me telling you that `x` is "a number" or that `x` is "the number 5." With `Student student;`, student is just a reference to a student that points to nothing. It's just a blank reference that *can* point to a `Student`. `Student student = new Student();` is a `Student` reference that points to a *particular* `Student`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a big difference!

1) Create a reference

```
Student student;
```

This command will tell the Java VM to create a field holding a reference. But at this time, there is no object stored, so this reference will go into nowhere - you will see this pretty often as a NullPointerException.

2) Creating an instance of your class

```
new Student();
```

This command will call your constructor (or Java's default constructor) and create a new instance of your class, with its own fields and stuff.

3) Assigning an instance to a field

```
Student student;
student = new Student();
```

Using this commands together, you are reserving space for a object, and create it as your next step. After creating, a reference to this object will be held in your student-field.

If you write these two lines in one, it looks like this, but the meaning is the same:

```
Student student = new Student();
```

Answer (score 0):

yes they are different `Student student;` just creates a reference where as `Student student = new Student();` creates an object and occupies some memory

Answer (score 0):

With

```
Student student;
```

you just define the type of variable. It contains right now `null` value.

```
Student student = new Student();
```

This one sets variable type and assigns new value to it, to `student` isn't `null` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.  Student student;
```

In this you are just creating the reference

```
2.  Student student = new Student();
```

In this you are allocating the object.

Answer (score 0):

Already mentioned, but can't resist myself:

1 is **Declaring** a var type of Student.

2 is declaring & **Defining** it as well.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st is a pointer ( that is it points to a Student object ) but it's null, means points nowhere ( no address space is reserved ). The 2nd is a pointer that refers to a full 'Student' object and memory address is reserved for this object ( means memory allocation ). So, if you try to reference the 1st one you will get NullPointerException but the 2nd one is a valid object.